# How to close the socket associated with current HttpClient instance?

Tags: android

I need to close it and create a new one, because I get socket exception when change the connection from 3g to wifi.

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrive the ClientConnectionManager associated with the instance and call shoutdown. If I had not misunderstood you:

```
HttpClient mClientInstance;    
ClientConnectionManager mConnectionManager = mClientInstance.getConnectionManager();
mConnectionManager.shutdown();
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work. Basically when my Android device switches from WiFi to 3G then its IP address that Web Server sees changes. So the old socket becomes useless. But the shutdown method doesn't close the socket.

Comment: how do you create the connection?

Comment: HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, TIME_OUT_LIMIT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, TIME_OUT_LIMIT);
            
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

Comment: in this simple way ; I have also tried to write a custom SchemeSocketFactory and attach to the current connection manager, but nothing has changed. I did this because I thought that the associated socket is not closed, so I closed it, and created a new one, in the SchemeSocketFactory.